# StopForumSpam and mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I'm looking to integrate the StopForumSpam mediawiki extension: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:StopForumSpam

I'm a little confused if $wgSFSIPListLocation is actually required, or if it can simply rely on the API? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the source tells me you will need to configure that parameter because it just returns if not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to set it since the default value is just 'false' and it would not work (see https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-StopForumSpam/blob/master/extension.json#L40)

Comment: Thanks, this is a bit of a pain then.